# Products import success but products not imported

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport

I am trying to import products using the system>import in Magento 2. 
The system say:

1. CSV file has no errors.
   [image]
2. Import works fine.
   [image]
3. But still no products are created from the given data.
   [image]
4. Also reindexed every index.

Where are the products which I just imported?

Comment: Magento Admin > System > Index Management. Please Reindex Catalag Product to view all the imported products.

Comment: I have done that too. I does not show any products. At least in Import History it should say how many products were imported even if they are now shown.

Answer (score 1):

Pandey,

Would you like to share your CSV with me so I could take the deep glance over there? What's your Magento version?

Thank You
Zuber